# GroupBox in WPF can only contain one element?

Tags: c#, wpf, groupbox

It seem that GroupBox can only contain one element, if I place more than one it's won't go inside(or get deleted in blend).

Is this by design or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

That sounds right to me. You'd need to put a Grid or Panel (StackPanel, WrapPanel, etc) as a child to define the layout.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, in WPF the GroupBox will contain maximum of 1 element. You can include Grid as its child and in grid specify your desired components. For example 1 placed two buttons in GroupBox using Grid.

Document Outline is shown below:

[image: Document Outline]

Code is as follow:

```
<GroupBox
            Header="Read Sensor"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="485,4,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Height="188"
            Width="238">
            <Grid
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Height="169"
                Margin="0,0,-13,-3"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="229">
                <Button
                    x:Name="btnReadSensor1"
                    Content="Read Sensor 1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="10,91,0,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Width="207"
                    Click="btnReadSensor1_Click" />
                <Button
                    x:Name="btnReadSensor2"
                    Content="Read Sensor 2"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="10,64,0,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Width="207"
                    Click="btnReadSensor2_Click" />
            </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 5):

Well the real answer is because groupbox inherits from HeaderedContentControl

Take a look here
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613548.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

You must drag the items: textbox INTO the groupbox and must only have a single groupbox.  Cannot drag more than a single groupbox per linear coordinate for it to work.  Can have multiple groupboxes on a page, but not more than a single column wide or you will be limited with only having a single item being added to the groupbox.